# Keep only Last value of a single index in multi-index in Pandas (drop_duplicates)

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

How can I get the last date on the multi-index dataframe.

I have simplified my df to the following:

```
Dates =['01/10/2017', '28/10/2018', '20/10/2019', '27/10/2019', '30/10/2019']
cols = ['Date', 'P1', 'P2', 'P3']
ProductIDs = [1, 1, 1, 3, 5]
df= pd.DataFrame(index = ProductIDs, columns= cols)
df.index.name = 'ProductIDs'
df.Date = Dates
df = df.reset_index().set_index(['ProductIDs', 'Date'])
df[:] = np.random.randint(0,20, size=(5,3))
df

                            P1  P2  P3
ProductIDs      Date            
1            01/10/2017     3   2   2
             28/10/2018     1   4   9
             20/10/2019     3   14  3
3            27/10/2019     3   1   7
5            30/10/2019     2   13  4
```

`df.groupby(level=[0]).last()` Gives me the result I want excluding the Date. How can I also see the date?

How can I get:

```
                            P1  P2  P3
ProductIDs      Date            
1            20/10/2019     3   14  3
3            27/10/2019     3   1   7
5            30/10/2019     2   13  4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First extract values of first level by [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html), check duplicates by [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) and invert condition by `~`. Last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[~df.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated(keep='last')]
print (df1)
                       P1  P2  P3
ProductIDs Date                  
1          28/10/2018  19   0   8
3          27/10/2019  16   2   3
5          30/10/2019  14   6   8
```

Detail:

```
print (df.index.get_level_values(0))
Int64Index([1, 1, 3, 5], dtype='int64', name='ProductIDs')

print (df.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated(keep='last'))
[ True False False False]

print (~df.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated(keep='last'))
[False  True  True  True]
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Is this possible to put into a .loc statement? I have a chain of .loc statements, and was wondering if this can also be included?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Use `df1 = df.loc[~df.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated(keep='last')]`

Comment: So my dates are in datetime, and my df only looks like that when I have:

    ```df2 = df.loc[(df.index.get_level_values('Start_Date')<=day) &
                (df.get_level_values('DOTW')==dotw)]```

where dotw = day of the week,

is there a way it can be chained to that loc? (just out of curiosity)

Comment: Yes, of course `df2 = df.loc[(df.index.get_level_values('Start_Date')<=day) & (df.get_level_values('DOTW')==dotw) & (~df.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated(keep='last'))]`

Comment: But there check duplicates in original `df`, not only in filtered df by first 2 conditions.

Comment: Yeah, as I suspected. I will use the first method. Thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160286/discussion-between-a-h-and-jezrael).